# Objective-C calendar component for Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, calendar

I need to integrate a calendar into my Mac app and I was wondering if anybody knows of a component. It can be free or paid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, did you find a solution finally?

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do with the calendar? If it's to pick dates, you can use a graphical `NSDatePicker`, which looks like a calendar.

Comment: I mean a Calendar View that shows all the Calendar´s events. Something like the Google Calendar Web UI.

Comment: I am looking for this, too. Since I already have a full data structure, a toolkit to easily manage the UI part of a calendar would suffice in my case. Any hints or pointers are more than welcome!

Comment: The more I am thinking about this, the more it appears that a simple calendar does not exist. There are many hidden problems, like how you should handle recurrent events, how the view should be laid out (and should there be a monthly, weekly, etc), and what exactly do you want to display in the "day-boxes". I'm in the process of writing it myself, it is a lot of work but at least I'll get what I want!